# Flutter animation not working: 'package:flutter/src/animation/curves.dart': Failed assertion: line 176 pos 12: 'begin <= 1.0': is not true

Tags: flutter, animation, flutter-animation

The animation is not working.

```
class TaskScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const TaskScreen({super.key, required this.animationController});

  final AnimationController animationController;
  @override
  _TaskScreenState createState() => _TaskScreenState();
}

class _TaskScreenState extends State<TaskScreen>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  final ScrollController scrollController = ScrollController();
  double topBarOpacity = 0.0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  Future<bool> getData() async {
    await Future<dynamic>.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 50));
    return true;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        color: AppTheme.background,
        child: BlocProvider(
          create: (context) => sl<TaskCubit>()..fetchTasks(),
          child: Scaffold(
            backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
            body: Stack(
              children: <Widget>[
                getMainListViewUI(),
                TopBar(
                  animationController: widget.animationController!,
                  title: 'My Task', 
                  scrollController: scrollController,
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).padding.bottom,
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ));
  }

  Widget getMainListViewUI() {
    return BlocBuilder<TaskCubit, TaskState>(
      builder: (context, state) {
        if (state is TaskLoadedState) {

          List<TaskEntity> tasks = state.tasks!.toList();
          List<Widget> listViews = <Widget>[];

          for (var task in tasks) {
            listViews.add(TaskItem(
                animationController: widget.animationController,
                animation: Tween<double>(begin: 0.0, end: 1.0).animate(
                    CurvedAnimation(
                        parent: widget.animationController!,
                        curve: Interval((1 / listViews.length) * 3, 1.0,
                            curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn))),
                taskSubject: task.subject!,
                taskProject: task.project!,
                taskStatus: task.status!,
                taskID: task.name!));
          }

          return ListView.builder(
            controller: scrollController,
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(
              top: AppBar().preferredSize.height +
                  MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top +
                  24,
              bottom: 72.5 + MediaQuery.of(context).padding.bottom,
            ),
            itemCount: listViews.length,
            scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              widget.animationController?.forward();
              return listViews[index];
            },
          );
        } else {
          return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

```
class TopBar extends StatefulWidget {
  final AnimationController animationController;
  final String title;
  final ScrollController scrollController;

  const TopBar({
    super.key,
    required this.animationController,
    required this.title,
    required this.scrollController,
  });

  @override
  _TopBarState createState() => _TopBarState();
}

class _TopBarState extends State<TopBar> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  Animation<double>? topBarAnimation;
  double topBarOpacity = 0.0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    topBarAnimation = Tween<double>(begin: 0.0, end: 1.0).animate(
      CurvedAnimation(
        parent: widget.animationController,
        curve: Interval(0, 0.5, curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn),
      ),
    );

    widget.scrollController.addListener(_handleScroll);

    super.initState();
  }

  void _handleScroll() {
    if (widget.scrollController.offset >= 24) {
      if (topBarOpacity != 1.0) {
        setState(() {
          topBarOpacity = 1.0;
        });
      }
    } else if (widget.scrollController.offset <= 24 &&
        widget.scrollController.offset >= 0) {
      if (topBarOpacity != widget.scrollController.offset / 24) {
        setState(() {
          topBarOpacity = widget.scrollController.offset / 24;
        });
      }
    } else if (widget.scrollController.offset <= 0) {
      if (topBarOpacity != 0.0) {
        setState(() {
          topBarOpacity = 0.0;
        });
      }
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        AnimatedBuilder(
          animation: widget.animationController!,
          builder: (BuildContext context, Widget? child) {
            return FadeTransition(
              opacity: topBarAnimation!,

              child: Transform(
                transform: Matrix4.translationValues(
                    0.0, 30 * (1.0 - topBarAnimation!.value), 0.0),

                child: ...
              ),
            );
          },
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

```
class TaskItem extends StatelessWidget {
  final AnimationController animationController;
  final Animation<double>? animation;
  final String taskSubject;
  final String taskProject;
  final String taskStatus;
  final String taskID;

  const TaskItem(
      {super.key,
      required this.animationController,
      required this.animation,
      required this.taskSubject,
      required this.taskProject,
      required this.taskStatus,
      required this.taskID});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AnimatedBuilder(
      animation: animationController!,
      builder: (BuildContext context, Widget? child) {
        return FadeTransition(
          opacity: animation!,

          child: Transform(
            transform: Matrix4.translationValues(0.0, animation!.value, 0.0),
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[...],
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

I bump into the error  `'package:flutter/src/animation/curves.dart': Failed assertion: line 176 pos 12: 'begin <= 1.0': is not true` at the bold line after debug. When I run the application, it display a red block and if I click to continue, it show the page I want to see, so I think it is a error showing the animation when widget appear on the page. These are the line I think I caught the error when debugging:

This is in the 2nd block code above.

```
builder: (BuildContext context, Widget? child) {
            return FadeTransition(
              opacity: topBarAnimation!,
              child: Transform(
                transform: Matrix4.translationValues(
                    0.0, 30 * (1.0 - topBarAnimation!.value), 0.0),
```

Thtis is in the 3rd block code above.

```
child: Transform(
            transform: Matrix4.translationValues(0.0, animation!.value, 0.0),
```

How can I fix this? Thank you!